# How does Daylight Saving Time work on a computer?

Tags: bios, date-time

I was wondering does the computer's time chip itself update the time, even when the computer is turned off (for example, the BIOS or OS send a command that when you reach a certain time you go back/forward 3600 seconds), or does the BIOS/OS update it the first time you start the computer after the DST has been in effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MC146818 real-time clock chip, as used in the IBM PC/AT, indeed had the capability to make DST changes on its own.  It only worked correctly in the United State and even then only worked correctly for a mere three years until the law was changed, and the DST rule that was hardwired into the chip circuitry no longer matched the actual DST rule.  This capability to update DST in hardware hasn't been used in decades.

If your operating system is a DOS Think operating system, then yes the DST changes are applied to the real-time clock by the operating system, and thus only when the machine is fully powered on and bootstrapped into the operating system.  However, this system has been known to be seriously and fundamentally broken for almost as long.  It has been discussed thoroughly in on-line discussion fora since the 1980s.

Unices and UNIX-like operating systems run the hardware RTC in UTC, and never apply *any* DST changes to it.  In fact, there isn't even any knowledge of DST in the operating system kernel.  The kernel and the hardware operate in UTC all of the time and a *system library function* applies a conversion from UTC to the local standard time/daylight-savings time based upon the `TZ` environment variable and an extensive on-disc timezone database.  There isn't a switchover between standard and daylight-savings time per se.  The conversion function simply yields the correct local time offset according to the time being converted.

Yes, the BSDs and Linux can be made to run in the DOS Think fashion, with the hardware clock running in something other than UTC.  This isn't a particularly good idea, and there's a lot of additional fragile mechanism that comes along with it.  For example, system managers such as `systemd` have to ensure that they have told the kernel about local time before `fsck` runs, because otherwise people in timezones that are ahead of UTC experience odd behaviour caused by the system clock going backwards during system startup.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2009). [*The DOS Think way of keeping time is fundamentally broken.*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/keeping-time-in-dos.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Andrey A. Chernov  (2012-03-08).  `adjkerntz`.  FreeBSD 9.2 manual pages.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard has a battery and a clock which will keep track of time even when the computer is off, however it is the OS which determines when to adjust the clock forward/backward depending on the settings. It doesn't get adjusted until either the OS is running at the time it is supposed to be changed, or upon the first boot afterwards.

Comment: There is NIST as well no? Sync via internet clock (as an example).

Comment: Correct in a sense. You can use Network Time Protocol (NTP), which in effect syncs your internal computer clock to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). However, this is still an OS function, and it only sets the clock to UTC (GMT in the old days). The OS Still has to convert that to your current time zone (e.g. I live close to Melbourne, Australia so it's GMT +10) and apply daylight savings to it if applicable.